# sqlite3_close_v2 crashes on iOS, sqlite3_close doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I'm writing some sqlite3 code in iOS for the first time. Every time I try and close the sqlite3 database connection with `sqlite3_close_v2(db)` where `db` is a `sqlite3 *` obtained from a call to `sqlite2_open_v2`, the application crashes with no helpful console output or other information **but only on an actual device - it doesn't crash in the simulator.**

Here's a code sample:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
int returnCode = 0;
if((returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], (int)strlen([query UTF8String])+1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK || statement == NULL) {
    Log(@"Failed to create query. code:%d",returnCode);
    sqlite3_close_v2(db);
}
```

The code will crash on the last line in the `if` statement when I pass a bad query. The code will not crash on the simulator, but it will crash on both an iOS 8 iPad and an iOS 7 iPod.

The crash is reported like this (this is not my own breakpoint, by the way):

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200e5088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

The breakpoint indicator says the crash is `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200e5088)`.

[image: Thread crash log]

Can anyone help me debug this? I've spent a lot of time googling around to no avail. For now, I'm going to just use `sqlite3_close(db)`, as this does not crash, but I'm worried about any consequences of using the `v2` `open` method with the non-`v2` `close` method...

**EDIT June 2016:** Never got an answer to this, and I've just stuck with using the `sqlite3_close` method instead, just in case anyone is wondering. As far as I know, it hasn't caused any issues...

Comment: Why are you closing the DB?

Comment: the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) states: `Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required.`

Comment: But you would do that when you leave the context where you opened the DB, right?  Basic "structured programming".

Comment: if there's a failure like this, I'll be returning out of these methods and not using the db connection anymore. not sure if that's what you're getting at... the `return` is just not included in the code sample for brevity

Comment: Well, you need to understand structured programming, but, setting that aside, what was the failing return code??

Comment: 1) Closing the database should only be paired with opening the database. 2) Don't close the database just because a statement couldn't be prepared. 3) `sqlite3_close_v2` is only supposed to be used in an environment with garbage collection. Therefore, under iOS, you should use `sqlite3_close`.

Comment: @HotLicks the return code is not relevant. I emulated a failure by writing a bad query to show that the failure was repeatable.

Comment: @rmaddy 1) the database was opened in earlier code. 2) why not? I will no longer be using the database connection at that point. the query will not be used, the code will return, and the app won't be accessing the database for some time. 3) I see that the [close docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) say that the method is intended for garbage collected environments, but it doesn't say it'll crash (and it's odd that the matching `v2` methods are to be used everywhere but `close`... isn't it?

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from the shared library loader. It might be that the device has an older version of SQLite that doesn't have the `close_v2` function, so the dyld fails to find it and crashes.

Comment: As @Colonel Thirty Two said, it's shared library loader error because running iOS version hasn't such function. I found you may use `sqlite3_close_v2` only since iOS 8.2. You should use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]]` to verify OS version.